# Moving files with update() and addParents in Google Drive API V3 not taking permanent effect

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

Trying to move a file to a folder using the update() method on the "parent" attribute, as per [this doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#moving_files_between_folders), and it seems to work initially, but the file "parents" update does not appear to have been "saved". The change to the name does work:

```
    $meta = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
        'name' => 'newName',
    ]);
    $file = $this->drive->files->update($fileId, $meta, [
        'addParents' => $dirId ,
        'removeParents' => '',
        'fields' => 'id, parents',
    ]);
    
    $file->getParents();   // This lists the new parent, $dirId. All looks well, but later...

    $file2 = $this->drive->files->get($fileId);
    $file2->getParents();  // ERROR: This has now reverted to having no parents!
    $file2->getName();     // This gets the new name however, which appears to be permanent
```

Using google-api-php-client v2.9.1 which is the latest at time of writing.
This is using Service Account credentials, and moving to a folder created by the Service Account. No errors are seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirmed that in the case of your script, in order to retrieve the parent folder ID, `$file2 = $this->drive->files->get($fileId)` is used. When you are using Drive API v3, the values of `kind`, `name`, `id` and `mimeType` are returned as the default response values. It seems that this is the current specification. I thought that the reason of your issue might be due to this.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$file2 = $this->drive->files->get($fileId);
```

- In this case, `"parents":null` is returned. So I thought that `$file2->getParents()` might be `ERROR: This has now reverted to having no parents!`.

#### To:

```
$file2 = $service ->files->get($fileId, array('fields' => 'name,parents'));
```

or

```
$file2 = $service ->files->get($fileId, array('fields' => '*'));
```

- By this modification, `fields` is used. By this, the values including `parents` are returned.

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem was. I also had a similar problem in using listFiles(), there the syntax is more obscure, 'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(name,parents)'.

Comment: @Dan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: 404 page not found :-(

Comment: @cloudxix About your question of `404 page not found :-(`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `404 page not found :-(`, I cannot understand your current situation. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Reference: Files: get - that link is *page not found*

Comment: @cloudxix From your reply of `Reference: Files: get - that link is page not found`, I cannot understand your situation. But, I would like to support you. So, in order to correctly understand your situation, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?